# Internal styling in Maui Blazor Hybrid apps

Tags: blazor, maui

How to use internal styling in Maui Blazor Hybrid apps? My code follows.

The background-color stying is ignored.

```html
    @page "/"
    <style>
        background-color : blue;
    </style>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    @code {
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ignored because it's not valid css.

You can either use inline style:

```
<h1 style="background-color: blue;">Hello, world!</h1>
```

Or define a css class:

```
<style>
    .bg-blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<h1 class="bg-blue">Hello, world!</h1>
```

But it's not good idea to add style tag inside razor component like that.

You should use "css isolation" which is a blazor feature.

**Index.razor**:

```
@page "/"

<h1 class="header">Hello, world!</h1>

@code {

}
```

Create **Index.razor.css**:

```
.header {
    background-color: blue;
}
```